# Completar expressão

Tags: php, regex, match

Bom, eu tenho algo como isso:

```
/^perfil[\/]?([0-9]{3})?[\/]?([a-z]{4,5})?[\/]?/i
```

E preciso criar uma função que, recebendo as devidas informações transforme isto em

```
perfil/431/abcd/
perfil/431/abcd
perfil/431/
perfil/431
perfil/
perfil
```

No entanto, esta função deve aceitar vários tipos de expressões como essa, e transformá-las mediante aos parâmetros informados. Como eu poderia fazer isso? eu cheguei a ver a função `preg_replace` mas eu não entendo bem como manipular estas expressões.

Então, o que eu preciso é uma função que receba algo como

```
/^perfil[\/]?([0-9]{3})?[\/]?([a-z]{4,5})?[\/]?/i
/^entrar[\/]?$/i
/^cadastro[\/]([0-9]{3})[\/]?$/i
```

E também recebesse os parâmetros dessas expressões,por exemplo, para

```
/^perfil[\/]?([0-9]{3})?[\/]?([a-z]{4,5})?[\/]?/i
```

Eu enviaria esta expressão, e enviaria de 0 a 2 parâmetros, para preencher `([0-9]{3})` e `([a-z]{4,5})`:

```
$expressao = "/^perfil[\/]?([0-9]{3})?[\/]?([a-z]{4,5})?[\/]?/i";
$valores = array(999, "zzzz");
$retorno = funcao($expressao, $valores);
```

E retorno neste caso seria igual a:

```
perfil/999/zzz
```

Mais um exemplo

```
$expressao = "/^cadastro[\/]([0-9]{3})[\/]?$/i";
$valores = array(999);
$retorno = funcao($expressao, $valores);
```

E neste caso, retorno seria igual a:

```
cadastro/999/
```

Ou seja, eu envio a expressão e os valores que eu preciso que sejam colocados nela, e a função retornaria a expressão completa

Comment: insira em sua pergunta alguns exemplos de "devidas informações" para que seja possível testar, do contrário como saberemos que tipo de string vai ser a entrada do seu algoritmo? estruture a pergunta da forma que contenha exemplos de entrada com exemplos de saída associados. por exemplo: vai receber uma string "a/a/a" e quero que minha expressão transforme "a/a/a" em "aaa"

Comment: Eu preciso que a função receba a expressão bruta como `/^perfil[\/]?([0-9]{3})?[\/]?([a-z]{4,5})?[\/]?/i` e os valores que eu preciso que sejam colocados nas lacunas, por exemplo, `array(999, 'ssss')`, e a função retornaria `perfil/999/ssss/`

Comment: é certeza que precisa e você quer usar o regex pra fazer isso que vc quer? pode ser que seja bem mais simples, dessa forma ai vai dar trabalho, particularmente nem sei como fazer

Comment: Não precisa ser necessariamente um regex, eu achei que dessa forma seria mais fácil, só preciso implementar esta funcionalidade de qualquer forma

Comment: O que você quer fazer se trata de um analisador lexer, [link sobre isso](http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP/), Eu recomendo você fazer por token, e não regex, vai ser mais simples.